# How to fix Recoverable fatal error: session_module_name(): Cannot set 'user' save handler by ini_set() or session_module_name()

Tags: php-7.3

I am getting error like below and how to fix it

> error for adodb library ...\adodb\session\adodb-session2.php on line 465.
>
> Recoverable fatal error: session_module_name(): Cannot set 'user' save handler by ini_set() or session_module_name()

Answer (score 4):

Please go to the php file

> db-functions-adodb.inc.php

and comment or remove the following line of code

> ini_set('session.save_handler', 'user');

Answer (score 1):

I found a [bug report in the PHP website](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77384) about this one.

The fact is that it was removed because it was not useful. Instead, you are expected to call the [`session_set_save_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) function and if you think about it, that's enough for clearly showing the intend.

So verify that your application does indeed call `session_set_save_handler()` if you want to make sure that the *user* mode is selected. As for that specific `ini_set()` line, you can just comment it out as Lakshmi said in his answer.